# What provisions entitle a defendant in a possession claim to receive on-the-day representation/advice from a duty scheme?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-aid, possession

Usually when facing a possession claim against oneself one is given access to a duty scheme advisor/representative. Suppose on one day there is no such representative present. Is a defendant who would have availed such advice had it been available seem to suffer any prejudice in the possession matter to which they are a party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no duty solicitor is available on the day, the defendant may make a [Part 23 Application](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part23#23.5) to the judge for an adjournment until they have had the opportunity to seek legal advice.

The power to adjourn in these circumstances may be found at [Rule 3.1(2)(b)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part03#3.1) Civil Procedure Rules:

> (2) ... the court may –
>
> ...
>
> - (b) adjourn ... a hearing
>
> ...

The only prejudice to the defendant that I can see with an adjournment is a prolonging of the process - but that needs to be balanced with ensuring the interests of justice are met.

---

For awareness, Shelter have a handy ["*Free legal help from a court duty scheme*"](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/eviction/free_legal_help_from_a_county_court_duty_scheme#:%7E:text=court%20duty%20scheme-,Free%20legal%20help%20from%20a%20court%20duty%20scheme,your%20income%20or%20financial%20situation.) guide, and there are a number of Housing Possession Court Duty Schemes [(HPCDS)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/housing-possession-court-duty-schemes-hpcds), such as [this from SWLLC](https://swllc.org/get-advice/housing/emergency-help-at-local-housing-courts/).